# Why should var keyword not be used in an instance and global variable declaration in Java 10

Tags: java, java-10

```
class Demo3 {
  
    // instance variable
    var x = 50;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/var-keyword-in-java/

Comment: It _shouldn't_ be used there because it _can't_ be used there, as the page you linked to says.  It would be syntactically incorrect to use it there.  If you're asking _why_ that decision was made, you'll have to ask the language designers.  "Why" questions are usually frowned upon here because the answers are just opinions.  (A why question might be OK if an answer could link to an authoritative source for the reasoning.)

Comment: Don't have a authoritative source, but your current `x` is non-private, meaning that it is part of the interface of `Demo3`. Which means a class that uses `Demo3` might fail to compile if you change the value of `x` without realizing that it changes the type inferred in place of `var`. The language designers, by forcing you to write the declared type for non-local variables, force you to acknowledge a change in an interface of a class.

Comment: Just imagine dealing with code where somebody has written 'var' for all of the fields.

Comment: [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68904692/507738) referring to an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

`var` can only be used for local variables. fields etc. were explictly excluded, see  [JEP 286](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

In an [Update on JEP 286](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/platform-jep-discuss/2016-December/000066.html), Java Language Architect Brian Goetz expressed a strong opinion about using it for fields:

"[...] is *fields* -- but applying type inference there would be foolish."

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The `var` keyword can only be used within a method scope while also being initialized immediately. Hence, instance variables can not be type inferred.